# SQL Server 2008 slqcmd data location

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlcommand, sqlcmd

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I've set the `Data` and `Log` locations to be `F:\moved\` by right-clicking the server in SQL Server Management Studio and setting them.

However when I restore a database using `sqlcmd` it restores the database to `E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA` which seems to be the default SQL Server location.

I need the databases to always be restored to `F:\moved\` for storage purposes but when I use the following in my script I *sometimes* get an error:

```
RESTORE DATABASE $(database) FROM DISK = '$(root)\$(database).bak' WITH RECOVERY,
MOVE '$(database)' TO '$(datadir)$(database).mdf',
MOVE '$(database)_log' TO '$(datadir)$(database).ldf'
GO
```

Error:

> Changed database context to 'master'.
>   Msg 3234, Level 16, State 2, Server SQL1, Line 3
>   Logical file 'userdb1' is not part of database 'userdb1'. Use RESTORE FILELISTONLY to   list the logical file names.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server SQL1, Line 3
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Can `sqlcmd` be forced to restore into `F:\moved\` by default, without having to specify it manually as I have above to avoid the error?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just define the `datadir` variable in your `sqlcmd` script?

Something like this:

```
:setvar datadir F:\moved\

RESTORE DATABASE $(database) FROM DISK = '$(root)\$(database).bak' WITH RECOVERY,
MOVE '$(database)' TO '$(datadir)$(database).mdf',
MOVE '$(database)_log' TO '$(datadir)$(database).ldf'
GO
```

With that line in place, `sqlcmd` should always use that directory (instead of the SQL Server default)

Or you could also set that variable value to anything you want on the command line invoking `sqlcmd`:

```
C:\> sqlcmd -v datadir=F:\moved\ (script name)
```

Comment: Ah, sorry, I already do this:
sqlcmd -S %4 -i restore.sql -v database="%1" -v root="%2" -v dbserver="%4" -v datadir="%6" -U sa -P testing that results in the error..

Comment: The reason I want it to default is because when I restore the database manually via SQL management studio it restores OK?